compose.yaml: services.web Additional property watch is not allowed
I am trying to run docker-compose up command in Windows, but I am getting this error.
Here is my compose.yaml file:
`
# version of docker compose
version: '3.8'
services:

# web service for react
  web:

  # where the docker file is located and other files to build docker image
    build: ./
 

    ports:
      - 5173:5173

    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules


    develop:
    watch:
    - path: ./package.json
      action: rebuild
      
    - path: ./package-lock.json
      action: rebuild


    - path: ./
      target: /app
      action: sync

`
Please tell me how to resolve this error and also why this error is happening.
I have recently installed Docker with the latest version.

You've declared the file as version: '3.8', but Compose file version 3 doesn't support a watch: option.  Are you using the old Python-based docker-compose tool; if you run docker-compose --version to get the version of the tool does it say version 1 or 2?

(It looks like this Compose setup isn't actually using anything in the Docker image; even if the watch: block works, the copy of node_modules in the Docker volume will take precedence and it won't be updated.  You might consider installing Node directly on your host and just running your code directly, without involving Docker at all.)
